# Jquery - How to restore defaults after use empty() Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have table and it has 2  tag. when i click hidden button then  will dissapear by using $().empty(). but i don't know how to restore. 
i don't want to use $().append or something like add new data. I want restore it.
How can i do that. thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('#hidden').click(function(){
        $('.hidden').empty();
    });
    $('#restore').click(function(){
        // restore defaults
    });
});
</script>
<table>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type = "button" id ='hidden' value="hidden"/>
<input type = "button" id ='restore' value="restore"/>
```

Comment: Don't ask questions like this. It could have taken only few minutes to  find the solution in one of the many tutorials available online. It seems that you never took any effort to solve this on your own, however here at stackoverflow you should only ask a question if you have really stucked with something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of emptying, you can simply hide and show the items.

```
$('#hidden').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').hide();
});
$('#restore').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').show();
});
```

Comment: this is a good solution ... .toggle() might be perhaps a bit more elegant, with only one button and another option could be to use .detach() as shown in the jquery example: http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 1):

Why not just using `hide` and `show`:

```
$(function(){
    $('#hidden').click(function(){
        $('.hidden').hide();
    });
    $('#restore').click(function(){
        // restore defaults
        $('.hidden').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to simply hide it (as already suggested), you can save it in an object.

```
$(function(){
    var data;
    $('#hidden').click(function(){
        data = $('.hidden').html();
        $('.hidden').empty();
    });
    $('#restore').click(function(){
        $('.hidden').html(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

empty() will remove content from dom, so it's lost forever
If you want only hide content, you should use

```
$.hide()
```

and then

```
$.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to restore content after calling .empty(). There is another function: .detach() that detaches selected elements from the DOM, but not fully erase them. After detaching the element can be appended again with .append() or .prepend().